# Frequency of drum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, elasticity

As picture blow, there are two drums, one is round drumhead , and another is elliptical drumhead. If the drumhead has same tension, I mean they are same tight , what is relation of their frequency ?

> [image]

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  Is there a particular concept that is giving you difficulties?  We are not here to solve exercise type problems for you..

Comment: You have asked a very difficult question to answer and perhaps you should read this paper by Gander and Wanner to give you an idea of what might be needed to be done. http://www.unige.ch/~gander/Preprints/Ritz.pdf

Comment: Hint: if the tension is zero the frequency is zero.

Comment: @ja72 That's not much of a clue! The fact that the frequency is the same when tension is zero does not imply the frequency will be the same at all other values of tension.

Comment: @JMac  It is not a exercise.  In math , there are many  questions about eigenvalue which is origin the wave equation. Recently, I want know how to change of eigenvalue  when boundary changing, but get stuck , so I want to see whether there is any good viewpoint  in physics

Comment: @lanse7pty then you should mention it in the question.

Comment: The solutions for all shapes of membrane are obtained by mathematical analysis rather than physical principles or insights. This is really a mathematical question, though the context is physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation 6.7 in [Vibration of Membranes](https://personal.egr.uri.edu/sadd/mce565/Ch6.pdf) gives the frequency of waves on a **rectangular membrane** as
$f=\frac{v}{2\pi}\sqrt{(\frac{m}{a})^2+(\frac{n}{b})^2}$
where $v=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\rho}}$ is the speed of waves on the membrane. which depends on density $\rho$ and tension $T.$ Here $a>b$ are the lengths of side of the rectangle and $m,n$ are the numbers of anti-nodes in each direction.

From this you can see that even for the fundamental mode $m=n=1$ the frequency is different for a square $(a=b)$ than for a rectangle $(a \ne b)$. In this case, if the area $A=ab$ is constant then we can write
$f=\frac{v}{2\pi}\sqrt{(\frac{b}{A})^2+(\frac{1}{b})^2}$
which is a minimum for the square $(b^2=A)$.

The equivalent result for **elliptical membranes** is more complex and can only be expressed numerically - see [Eigenfrequencies of an Elliptic Membrane](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1973-27-124/S0025-5718-1973-0421276-2/S0025-5718-1973-0421276-2.pdf).

In Appendix A an expansion is given for the fundamental mode $(m=n=1)$ in terms of $x=1-\frac{b}{a}$ which has a maximum error of $0.0002$ :
$2\pi \frac{bf}{v}=2.4048-1.1924x+0.1768x^2+0.3923x^3-0.2107x^4$
where $2b$ is the minor axis of the ellipse. You could use this to compare the frequencies for the circle and ellipse.

In Appendix B the authors state that $f/\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}}$ is approximately constant for eccentricities up to about $0.65$, noting that this applies also for rectangles of any size. Unfortunately they do not state whether the area or the major axis is constant, nor whether this result applies only for the fundamental mode or for all modes.

As for rectangular membranes, the lowest frequency for any mode of an ellipse of constant area is found when the ellipse is a circle. As you note, for a given area the circle has the lowest frequency of any shape of membrane.

Comment: I think so. But in your example the circle and ellipse do not have the same area.